# React-beautiful-dnd: Prevent page from scrolling when draggable is being dragged near edge of page

Tags: css, reactjs, drag-and-drop, autoscroll, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using react-beautiful-dnd in a project and when I'm dragging a draggable, the page auto scrolls if I drag it near the top, bottom or sides of the page. I could theoretically fix this problem by placing the drag and drop container in the middle of the page so that the user probably wouldn't trigger the auto scroll as the draggable wouldn't be dragged to the edges of the page, but I'd prefer not to alter the layout in that way. Is there any way to disable the auto scrolling?